# NodeJS - wait for callbacks to finish

Tags: node.js, express

Pusedo-code:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    request(url, callback1) //callback1 alters 'index' template a bit
    request(url, callback2) //callback2 alters 'index' template a bit
    request(url, callback3) //callback3 alters 'index' template a bit

    res.render('index'); //Have to render after callback1,2,3 are done
});
```

How do I make sure `render` is only called after all callbacks are resolved?

PS. The URLs are different for each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain a counter for all the asynchronous calls and render the res if counter is equal to number of asynchronous calls.

Below is code snippet for the same:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var count = 0; 
    request(url1, function(err, data) {
       count++;
       // something to be done
       if(count == 3) {
          res.render('index'); 
       }  
    });
    request(url2, function(err, data) {
       count++;
       // something to be done
       if(count == 3) {
          res.render('index'); 
       }  
    });
    request(url3, function(err, data) {
       count++;
       // something to be done
       if(count == 3) {
          res.render('index'); 
       }  
    });
```

You can use for loop on urls instead of writing different request block if the task to be done is same in each callback.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise):

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  request(url)
    .then(callback1)
    .then(() => request(url))
    .then(callback2)
    .then(() => request(url))
    .then(callback3)
    .then(() => res.render('index'));
 });
```

Comment: Just did a new edition, in case callbacks return promises

Answer (score -1):

Node promise module will be helpful.
By using that module response can be send after executing all call backs.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Ok i will remove it now